# Updating Table from vb to Access using ConnectionString

Tags: vb.net

```
 Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click

    Try
        Dim con As New SqlConnection
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand

        con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=E:\Comp-296\Project1\Project1\Game_time.mdb"
        con.Open()
        cmd.Connection = con

        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.CommandText = ("UPDATE User_Name SET User_Name = @User_Name, Game_Name = @Game_Name, Score = @Score, Time/Date = @Time/Date")
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@User_Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtUser.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Game_Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtGame.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Score", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtScore.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Time/Date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = txtDate.Text

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MessageBox.Show("Data Update successfully")
        con.Close()
    Catch ex As System.Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Data Update has failed")
    End Try

End Sub
```

The code is giving an Exception is an ArgumentException and also :Keyword not supported: 'provider'.

Comment: You are using Access. You need to use OleDbConnection (and all the classes from OleDb)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using Access. This database cannot be opened using the classes in System.Data.SqlClient. These classes are used when you want to connect to Sql Server, Sql Server Express or LocalDB.

If you want to reach an MSAccess database you need the classes in System.Data.OleDb and these classes are OleDbConnection, OleDbCommand etc...

Said that, please note, that your field Date/Time will give you headaches. Change that name or put always square brackets around it because the / will be interpreted as the division operator

So your code could be:

```
Using con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=E:\Comp-296\Project1\Project1\Game_time.mdb")
Using cmd = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE User_Name 
      SET User_Name = @User_Name, 
          Game_Name = @Game_Name, 
          Score = @Score, [Time/Date] = @dt", con)
    con.Open()
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@User_Name", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = txtUser.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Game_Name", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = txtGame.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Score", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = txtScore.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@dt", OleDbType.Date).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDate.Text)

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    MessageBox.Show("Data Update successfully")
End Using
End Using
```

Other notes:
Disposable objects like the connection and the command should be enclosed inside a Using Statement to be disposed and closed as soon as possible.
The time field requires a DateTime value not a string. If you pass a string you will face the automatic conversion made by the engine and sometime the engine is unable to produce a valid date from your input string. This will raise another exception (DataType mismatch). Better check and convert the value before passing it.

Also the type of the parameters should be from the OleDbType enum.

Comment: Its saying that: Error 'DateTime' is not a member of System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType'. ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized.

Comment: Right it is just OleDbType.Date

Comment: ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized. I'm getting an exception